# Dynamically populating textArea in Flashbuilder

Tags: php, sql, apache-flex, textarea, flash-builder

I cant seem to populate a textArea dynamically in flash builder. The only tutorials I can find are populating dataGrids or drop downs using a dataProvider. Heres the code I am using:

```
<s:HTTPService id="noteService"
                   url="http://localhost/webAppIntergration%20Thur/Assignment/servicePipe.php?action=getNoteXML"
                   />
```

The HTTPService gets sent when the app is created. And here is the textArea code I tried:

```
<s:TextArea text="{noteService.lastResult.notess.notes}"/>
```

The only thing that gets returned to the textArea is "[object Object]" so I guess I have to change it to a different type or a string before it can be output to a textArea field but i'm not 100% sure on how to do this.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some thing like below code to populate dynamic string to your defined text area: -

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            //parse your result or type cast.
            textArea.text = noteService.lastResult.notess.notes
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TextArea id="textArea"/>
    <s:HTTPService id="noteService"
                   url="http://localhost/webAppIntergration%20Thur/Assignment/servicePipe.php?action=getNoteXML"
                   result="resultHandler(event)"
                   fault="trace('fault')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I did try this method but your answer got me thinking more into it and I realised I needed to include a third XML node like this: "noteService.lastResult.notess.notes.note". I never tried it like this before because it was outputting into a dataGrid fine without defining the third node, therefore I thought it was an error with the type. But yeah thanks for your help!